# Place Google translate API function into an external JS file

Tags: javascript, xss

I came across this page which explains how to use the Google API to translate your page.
The issue here is that the Javascript explained is all inline.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

In order to avoid XSS problems, I want to place this as a function or two in an external JS file and load it in the footer. Since there are two scripts being called, and the second just seems to be the API being called, how would this be placed in JS file together?

Comment: Where do you think you are at risk of XSS? I'm not seeing anything obvious here.

Comment: Any inline script is open to XXS. Best practice, as I have been recently informed about, is to place any JS script in an external file.

Comment: An inline script is not an XSS risk by itself. It's perfectly fine. It is when you inject untrusted & unescaped user input into attributes or generating markup or script dynamically (for example) that you are likely at risk. Nothing I see in your post suggests that you're taking any input at all. If this was malicious code then putting it in a different file instead of inlining it in your html offers zero protection whatsoever.

Comment: Well, i want to first hide this with a dialog that says "You will now be using Google's API, please note their Data privacy policy here. "url....". So I will be adding a furhter functionality to only show the Google translate button, only one they confirm.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this though?

Answer (score 2):

After some working through this, I have found the solution. This solution means that Googles Translate API only gets called after the user confirms they are ok with the API being called and not upon page load.

```
 //call Google translate api
 function google_translate_api(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Add the other Google function to the JS file:

```
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'de'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

Then add a click event to the button `I agree to Google API`

```
document.getElementById("google_consent").onclick = function(){
google_translate_api();
}
```

Naturally, i have also added a cookie part, so that if the user comes back later, the Google API will load automatically and won't be asked again to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried puting all this into js, but i got errors. Ifunction googleTranslateElementInit is not working properly.

```
script_19.js?t=295a5363e4:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at googleTranslateElementInit (script_19.js?t=295a5363e4:2:39)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script_19.js?t=295a5363e4:5:160)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.js:2:43064)
at v.handle (jquery.js:2:41048)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).